# facebox cancel event

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

Im using facebox for delete data (conformation) from MySQL. i like to know how to use a cancel button in the window. when the user click cancel facebox have to unload.

Here is the code im using in facebox.

```
Are You Sure You Want To Delete This URL?
<?php
include ('../db.php');

$id = $_GET['id'];
        if (isset($id))
        {
$query = "DELETE * FROM posts WHERE post_id='$id'";
}?>
<br/>
<br/>
<?php
echo '<a href="index.php?del='.$id.'" class="button" >Yes</a>';
echo '<a href="#" class="button" >Cancel</a>';


?>
```

what is the code i have to use in cancel button? thanks in advance.

Link to facebox : http://defunkt.io/facebox/

Comment: Are you asking how to cancel the AJAX call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jQuery(document).trigger('close.facebox');
```